# Chat con python 3.8.2 mediante sockets y tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, socket

Últimamente me propuse realizar un chat mediante `sockets` **cliente-servidor** usando `tkinter`

El problema que obtuve es que no sé que hacer para que el texto obtenido del *cliente* mediante sockets lo coloque en un **label** de tkinter, debido a que la variable está en otra función a la de tkinter que no es posible quitar las funciones a causa de que tengo que ejecutarlas en segundo plano mediante módulo  `threading`.

El error que me arroja es: `"msg" is not defined`

Muchas gracias de antemano

**Código del server:**

```
import socket
import threading 
from tkinter import *
#CREACIÓN DEL SOCKET
def sock3t():
    tkinter_thread =threading.Thread(target = tkinter1)
    tkinter_thread.start()
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind( ("localhost", 8000) )
    sock.listen(7)
    while True: 
        recibido = sock.accept()[0]
        msg = recibido.recv(1024).decode("ascii")
        print(msg)
def tkinter1():
    ventana= Tk()
    ventana.title("CHAT")
    ventana.configure(background="white")
    ventana.resizable(0,0)
    ventana.geometry("800x525")
    cuadro_de_texto = Entry(ventana,selectborderwidth=0,font="ansii",width=70,bd=1)
    cuadro_de_texto.pack()
    cuadro_de_texto.place(x=200, y=500)
    label= Label(ventana,text="hola",background="white",font="ansii")
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=200, y=467)
    Botón = Button(ventana,text=msg,font="ansii",relief=RAISED,width=19,)
    Botón.pack()
    Botón.place(x=627,y=500)
    ventana.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sock3t()
```

**Código del cliente:**

```
import socket
while True:
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect( ("localhost", 8000) )
    msg= ("hola!")
    envio= (msg.encode("ascii"))
    sock.send(envio)
```

Comment: ¿No puedes invocar a `tkinter1()` dentro de `sock3t()` y usar `msg` como parámetro?

Comment: @Gabitohh Deben estar en funciones diferentes, ya que si las coloco en una sola función no puedo ejecutarlas en diferentes planos